# Youtrack: Resubmission after n days possible?

Tags: youtrack

I have a ticket in our custom youtrack which is assigned to me.

I contacted the customer and he wants to give me the needed information in the next week.

I want to this issue to vanish out of my "assigned to me and open" view for 7 days.

What is the most easy way to do this?

My favourite solution wearing the "I am a lazy user" glasses looks like this: `+7 ENTER` :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess while the details are not provided by customer, you can set State of the issue to "Wait for reply" or similar.
Once the customer replied with details, the State will be updated with "Open" value. For example, if the user is not included in one of internal groups, re-opening can be achieved with workflow:

rule **Reopen on answer**

```
when State=={Wait for Reply} && comments.added !=null 
    && comments.added.isNotEmpty && comments.added.last !=null 
    && !comments.added.last.author.isInGroup("Internal Developers"){

    State={Open};
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could work. Nevertheless I would like to reopen after N days. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Initially I wanted to suggest to use Scheduled rule, which will count days since target change (moving issue to "Wait for reply"). But I played around and found it's not actually possible to access issue's History, and thus- target change. Still, you can add new field, say, "Counter".When the issue will become "Wait for reply", "0" will be set to "Counter". Then, daily schedule rule will remove current value and replace it with the value increased to 1. Daily the value will be compared to "7". When the value in "Counter" becomes == 7, then update "State" to "Open".

Comment: I can follow you, but only in theory. I am user of youtrack not someone who implements youtrack modules :-)